# Bool tool is not shown even though it's enabled

Tags: add-on

I enabled the Bool Tool in my Blender 4.1:
[image]

However, the tool is not shown in my `View3D>Sidebar>Edit`. The hotkey (Ctrl Shift B) also doesn't work. Would I need additional steps to enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image shows that you're looking at Blender's main <kbd>Edit</kbd> menu.
Hit the <kbd>N</kbd> key to show the tools sidebar and then the <kbd>Edit</kbd> tab (arrowed) to show the <kbd>Bool Tools</kbd> entry (hilighted below).

[image]

I imagine that you would also need to have two objects selected in <kbd>Object</kbd> mode for the hotkey to display the popup menu but to be honest I've only ever used the <kbd>Numpad</kbd> shortcut keys with the <kbd>Bool Tool</kbd> here.